# htaccess modrewrite php link uniq

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here's my default link

```
http://localhost/details.php?title=example
```

title=M , M is a column in MYSQL and the file read the rest of information of the specified title, so I want to rewrite to look like this:

```
http://localhost/example/
```

I want to be after root domain only the title of the post I tried in a few times with modrewrite but it dosen't work, I don't know where I wrong. How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: "I tried in a few times with modrewrite but it doesn't work" So show what you've tried and explain how the result is different from what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this n your document root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+details\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ details.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I see you specify something for M value but not there i'm interested read again what I say to understand.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: I want to do from localhost/details.php?title=example to localhost/example/

Comment: The page is open but without css and i got this error: Notice: Undefined index: title in...

Comment: Sorry the first code work but I already say without css and with an error, with your updated code dosen't work i got 404 error.

Comment: which URL gets you 404? css is different problem due to your use of relative links.

Comment: DO you have any other rule also OR any CMS/PHP framework running?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49685/discussion-between-john-smith-and-anubhava)